# How to know whether versioning is enabled on an S3 bucket in command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

We have multiple S3 buckets, in which some are having s3 versioning enabled and some are disabled. How to know which bucket is enabled with versioning?

Is it possible disable s3-versioning on a sub-object (sub-folder) when S3-bucket(Main folder) is enabled with versioning?

Answer (score 6):

The following command retrieves the versioning configuration for a bucket named my-bucket:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-versioning --bucket my-bucket
```

If the bucket is version enabled you will the below mentioned output

```
{
    "Status": "Enabled"
}
```

If you want to check all the bucket is version enabled you can write a small shell script to list the buckets and check the version. For more information visit http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-versioning.html

Comment: I made this call, but it doesn't return me any response. Does this mean my versioning is not enabled, or means the call didn't make it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get anything back, versioning isn't enabled for that particular bucket.  You probably will want to echo the bucket in your loop so you can see which ones have it enabled vs. not